# MySQL index for in and order by clause

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, database-indexes

I have a table with columns

```
user (id, name, username, company, salary)
```

What will be the best index strategy for these two queries

```
select * from user where company in ("a", "b") order by salary limit 20
```

and

```
select * from user order by salary limit 20
```

Comment: The minimal 'useful' index is `INDEX(salary)`; it will help both queries.  Maximal -- see Tim's answer.  If you have under a thousand rows, the indexes won't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to be `index(company, salary)`. Consider that ordering of indexes is important to notice.

Comment: Note that MySQL may choose to not even use this index.

Comment: That order will probably be used by the first query, but not by the second.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following covering index for the first query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON user (company, salary, name, username);
```

The `name` and `username` columns are included to cover the `SELECT *`, which requires all columns.

For the second query, you may try:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON user (salary, company, name, username);
```

Comment: What is the reason to index `name` and `username`?

Comment: @agtabesh he clearly mentioned in his post, it's due to `select *`

Comment: @James Only index those columns that are required in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses. Indexing every column reduces the write speed without affecting on read speed. Other thing to notice is fetching a row is not costly as finding it.

Comment: @agtabesh - Partially false.  In the case of a "covering" index, the extra columns make the read run faster.  You have 5 columns in the table.  The index explicitly lists 4 of them.  `id`, assuming it is the `PRIMARY KEY`, is implicitly tacked onto the end of each secondary key.  More discussion and examples:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql